# mysql both commit and set a variable if a certain condition applies?

Tags: mysql

For example,

```
IF ----
THEN SET variable = 0 
AND COMMIT;

ELSE
SET variable = 1
AND ROLLBACK;

END IF;
```

What would be the syntax for this type of query?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Multiple statements which belong together have be included in a `BEGIN ... END` block.

```
IF whatever = true THEN 
BEGIN
    SET variable = 0;
    COMMIT;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET variable = 1;
    ROLLBACK;
END
END IF;
```